# Get 10+ Level Hierarchy Relationship

Tags: apex, force.com, account

I have an account A10 its parent Id is A9 further A9 has parentId A8 and it goes on and on say upto A1. Is there any way to get all the parent accounts ?

A10 -> A9 -> A8 -> A7 -> A6 -> A5 -> A4 -> A3 -> A2 -> A1

```
public class childs
{
    public id accId{get;set;}
    public String ids;
    public childs()
    {
         for(Account acc : [Select id, name, parentId From Account where Id ='0012800000krmWZ'])
        {
            ids = ids + ' : '  +acc.parentId;
            while(accId != null)
            {
                accId = acc.parentId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Updates

```
 <apex:selectList value="{!accId}" size="1" style="margin: 10px;"> 
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!allAccounts}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport action="{!clearList}" event="onchange" rerender="pb, pm" />
               ----------- {!idList}
            </apex:selectList>

public void clearList()
{
    idList.clear();
    fetchParentRecord();
}

public void fetchParentRecord()
{
  /*  if(i==0)
        idList.clear();
        i++;*/
    List<Account> lstAccount = [SELECT ParentId, parent.name, Id FROM Account WHERE Id =: accId];
    if(!lstAccount.isEmpty())
    {
        idList.add(lstAccount[0].parent.name);
        accId = lstAccount[0].parentId;
        system.debug('######'+idList);
        fetchParentRecord();
       // if(accId == null || accId == '')
         //   i=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: how many level you are expecting ? have you tried anything?

Comment: @ratan till the relationship ends. I wonder if it is even possible.

Comment: if you see as business logic, you won't  found any account with more than 15 levels (max).

Comment: ok how could go to 15 levels. is there any way ?

Comment: you need to create recursive method. you need to pass the parentid each time  and based on parent Id get the child record. This process will be repeat until there is no child record. basically this is the idea. Now try your self

Comment: @Ratan I have edited my code, is there any way to avoid loop inside loop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can create a method and collect the parentid if parentId is not null then again call the same method and pass the next parentId.

This way you will able to get all the hierarchy records.

This may fail due to soql 101 error for the so many level of account hierarchy

```
public id accId{get;set;}
public String ids;

public childs()
{
    //pass first account record Id 
    fetchParentRecord(accId);
}

//this method will iterate untill the parent Id is null
private void fetchParentRecord(Id recordId)
{
   //each time query on Account and get the get the parent Id
    List<Account> lstAccount = [SELECT ParentId, Id FROM Account 
                                 WHERE Id =: recordId AND ParentId != null];
    // if list is not empty then based on parent Id get the next above Account
    if(!lstAccount.isEmpty()){
        ids = ids + ' : '  +lstAccount[0].parentId;
        fetchParentRecord(lstAccount[0].parentId);
    }
}
```

### Updates

```
public id accId{get;set;}

public void clearList()
{
    idList.clear();
    fetchParentRecord(accId);
}

public void fetchParentRecord(Id accId)
{

    List<Account> lstAccount = [SELECT ParentId, parent.name, Id 
                                  FROM Account WHERE Id =: accId];
    if(!lstAccount.isEmpty())
    {
        idList.add(lstAccount[0].parent.name);
        system.debug('######'+idList);
        fetchParentRecord(lstAccount[0].parentId);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 thing I want to know is that how are we going to clear the list in recursive function it would be too difficult?

Comment: @Anzar what do you mean clear the list ?

Comment: I am selecting a record from a picklist, based on selection its parent are coming. Now When I select another record the list gets populated with the records that were previously there in the list. Before selecting the record list need to be cleared.

Comment: @Anzar when you select any value in picklist. You must be calling a function. So whenever that function is get called just make ids string to empty

Comment: its a recursive function, calling itself again and again everytime it calls it will empty the list.

Comment: @Anzar no man, don't call fetchParentRecord method fro page. First call a function and make the list empty then after call the fetchParentRecord  method like, how we called from constructor

Comment: I have edited my code. Everything is working fine except when I select a record from picklist, selected value is getting refreshed.

Comment: @Anzar you are doing correct except the passing the id in method as parameter

Comment: I didn't get you.

Comment: hey ratan I have done it code is working properly can you please explain me why should we pass id?. I will be thankful to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46026/discussion-between-ratan-and-anzar).

Answer (score 3):

This will get all parents and children of the starting account and all the parents children. Basically anything related to the starting account and accounts related to all of the relations. The whole family tree if you will.

Here is one way to do it:

```
Account theAccount = //Your SOQL/Starting Account Here
Set<ID> AllParents = new Set<ID>();
Boolean allDone;

AllParents.add(theAccount.ID);
      //If the account we are starting at has a Parent ID, add it
      //to the set of IDs
      if(theAccount.ParentID != Null){
        AllParents.add(theAccount.ParentID);
      }

      //Main loop to traverse through the Hierarchy
      do{
         //Set the flag to indicate loop should stop
         allDone = true;
        //Get a list of accounts with IDs or Parent IDs in the AllParents Set
        //This will produce 1 SOQL for each level in the Hierachy 
        //Max is then 99 levels deep which I believe no one will  have
        //You could add a check though
        for(Account a : [Select ID, ParentID From Account Where ID IN :AllParents OR ParentID IN :AllParents]){

          if(!AllParents.contains(a.ID) || ( !AllParents.contains(a.parentID) && a.parentID != null)){

            if(a.parentID != null)
              AllParents.add(a.parentID);

            AllParents.add(a.id); //Comment this out if you just want to go up through the parents of the starting account and not get the parents children
            //Reset flag to find more parents / children
            allDone = false;

          }

        }

      } while(allDone == false);
```

Keep in mind limits etc.

You can modify as needed to NOT get the other children of the parents

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only parent id in your child. creating custom formula field on each child object and append id(any field whichever required) of parent. Here we go!!.

A2
    Formula Text field to store A1 Id

A3
    Formaula Text field to store A1 id + append A2 Id

A4
    Formaula Text field to store A1 id + append A2 Id + append A3 Id

A5
    Formaula Text field to store A1 id + append A2 Id + append A3 Id + append A4 Id

etc..

is this works for you solution.