# Traverse a Relationship of Unknown Depth

Tags: apex, relationships, loop

**Update:** Okay so this was marked as a duplicate, which I can appreciate, because it is similar to the question posed here: [Get 10+ Level Hierarchy Relationship](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142160/get-10-level-hierarchy-relationship) - however, I believe mine differs slightly in the sense that I am specifically looking for a way to do this without querying inside a loop/without recursive or constant SOQL Queries. I am trying to run this code on every account in our system simultaneously, roughly 19,000 records - so doing a SOQL query every time I want to get the next relationship / parent record in the chain doesn't seem ideal. I could do it I suppose, by building this into a batch class of some sort that only processes a few accounts at a time, but I was looking for a solution I could run against my entire database simultaneously. Is there no way to accomplish this without constantly querying SOQL for the new record every time? Unless I am missing something, the suggested answer in [Get 10+ Level Hierarchy Relationship](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142160/get-10-level-hierarchy-relationship) would only work up to ~100 times in a transaction before hitting the SOQL Query limit.

> **Issue:** My company had a nasty prior habit of creating duplicate account records every time one of our customers cancelled and then
>   returned to us, or every time they changed ownership. They would
>   create a new account & contacts, relate the new account to the old
>   account via a custom Account(Self) Lookup field, and then sell new
>   opportunities/products to that new account. If that same customer
>   cancelled or changed ownership again, they would repeat the whole
>   process. Over, and over.
>
> This has resulted in some situations where there may be a Parent-Child
>   relationship of unknown depth of Account > Account > Account > Account > Account > etc.

---

I've since then created a new Customer Lifecycle tracking system that creates new related records on a single account to track a customers activation/cancellation journey with our company - now I am trying to deal with the cleanup of all of these old very fragmented account records.

> **Goal:** Essentially what I want to do is, starting from the "Most Recent" account, which I determine via it having a Legacy_Account__c
>   Parent object, and also having no child Accounts in that relationship,
>   traverse up each Parent in this tree, stopping at each account along
>   the way to collect some key data from the record and convert that data
>   into a Customer Lifecycle record that's related to the Most Recent
>   account before moving on to the next parent, and so on and so on,
>   until I reach the "top" of the tree.

---

> **Problem:** Every account could have a different amount of 'hops' between their most recent account and their first account, so I have
>   no way of knowing how many levels deep to go, so I'm trying to come up
>   with a way to do this dynamically using an Integer for loop or perhaps a
>   While loop until a condition is met, but every time I try to tackle it
>   I end up doing a bunch of SOQL inside loops which is not scalable.

---

I think I'm on the right track using a while loop, but the code I've written so far seems to only succeed in building one record in the list and store it in the map even when I know for a fact that there are account relationships that have more than one level to traverse through. It's late and I've been poking around at this code for a while now, so I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes might be able to point out some key flaws in my approach and help guide me to Valhalla.

**Code:**

```
        Map<Id,List<Account_Lifecycle__c>> AccIdToLifeCycleListMap = new Map<Id,List<Account_Lifecycle__c>>();
        Map<Id,Account> accMap = New Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,ParentId,Platform_Application__c,Anniversary_Date__c,AccountCancellationDate__c,Cancellation_Reason__c,Inadequate_Available_Features__c,Switched_to_Competitor__c,Legacy_Account__c,(Select Id,Name FROM Accounts2__r) FROM Account]);
        Id masterId;
        Id nextId;
        Account masterAccount;
        Account nextAccount;
        Boolean nextLevel;
        Integer level;

        for(Account a : accMap.values()){
            if(a.Legacy_Account__c != null && a.Accounts2__r.size() == 0){
                AccIdToLifeCycleListMap.put(a.Id,new List<Account_Lifecycle__c>());
            }
        }

        for(Id record : AccIdToLifeCycleListMap.keySet()){
            List<Account_Lifecycle__c> lcList = new List<Account_Lifecycle__c>();
            masterId = record;
            masterAccount = accMap.get(masterId);
            level = 0;
            nextLevel = true;
            While(nextLevel){
                if(level == 0){
                    nextId = masterAccount.ParentId;
                    level++;
                }else{
                    nextId = nextAccount.ParentId;
                    level++;
                }
                nextAccount = accMap.get(nextId);
                if(nextAccount != null){
                    lcList.add(new Account_Lifecycle__c(Account__c = masterId,
                                                        Platform_Application__c = nextAccount.Platform_Application__c,
                                                        Anniversary_Date__c = nextAccount.Anniversary_Date__c,
                                                        Cancellation_Date__c = nextAccount.AccountCancellationDate__c,
                                                        Cancellation_Reason__c = nextAccount.Cancellation_Reason__c,
                                                        Inadequate__c = nextAccount.Inadequate_Available_Features__c,
                                                        Switched_To_Competitor__c = nextAccount.Switched_to_Competitor__c));
                }else{
                    nextLevel = false;
                }
            }
            AccIdToLifeCycleListMap.put(masterId,lcList);
            System.debug('Records : ' + AccIdToLifeCycleListMap.get(masterId));
        }
```

Comment: I had implemented something similar to traverse the account hierarchy. See this [**post**](https://jdspaceit.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/traversing-through-an-accounts-hierarchy-in-apex/), if it helps you someway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while the post was temporarily closed as a duplicate I kept playing with it, added some debug lines to it and ultimately figured out that its working great, but I accidentally was referencing ParentId instead of my custom relationship field.

Once I stepped through the code and realized my late night mistake, I've determined that this is a good baseline example of how to traverse through a chained relationship of unknown length without doing multiple in-loop or recursive SOQL Queries. I'll leave this code here for anyone who may come across it in the future:

```
public static void ConvertAccounts(){
    Map<Id,List<Account_Lifecycle__c>> AccIdToLifeCycleListMap = new Map<Id,List<Account_Lifecycle__c>>();
    Map<Id,Account> accMap = New Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,ParentId,Legacy_Account__r.Id,Platform_Application__c,Anniversary_Date__c,AccountCancellationDate__c,Cancellation_Reason__c,Inadequate_Available_Features__c,Switched_to_Competitor__c,Legacy_Account__c,(Select Id,Name FROM Accounts2__r) FROM Account]);
    List<Account_Lifecycle__c> lifeCyclesToInsert = new List<Account_Lifecycle__c>();
    Id masterId;
    Id nextId;
    Account masterAccount;
    Account nextAccount;
    Boolean nextLevel;
    Integer level;

    for(Account a : accMap.values()){
        if(a.Legacy_Account__c != null && a.Accounts2__r.size() == 0){
            AccIdToLifeCycleListMap.put(a.Id,new List<Account_Lifecycle__c>());
        }
    }

    for(Id record : AccIdToLifeCycleListMap.keySet()){
        List<Account_Lifecycle__c> lcList = new List<Account_Lifecycle__c>();
        masterId = record;
        masterAccount = accMap.get(masterId);
        System.debug('Master Account: ' + masterAccount + 'Master ID: ' + masterId);
        level = 0;
        nextLevel = true;
        While(nextLevel){
            System.debug('Status Check: Level = ' + level + ' while next = ' + nextLevel);
            if(level == 0){
                nextId = masterAccount.Legacy_Account__r.Id;
                System.debug('Level: ' + level + ' : Next Id Should be Parent of Master: ' + nextId);
                level++;
                System.debug('New Level: ' + level);
            }else{
                nextId = nextAccount.Legacy_Account__r.Id;
                System.debug('Level: ' + level + ' Next Id is: ' + nextId);
                level++;
                System.debug('New Level: ' + level);

            }
            nextAccount = accMap.get(nextId);
            System.debug('Next Account: ' + nextAccount);
            if(nextAccount != null){
            System.debug('Next Account Not Null');
                lcList.add(new Account_Lifecycle__c(Account__c = masterId,
                                                    Platform_Application__c = nextAccount.Platform_Application__c,
                                                    Anniversary_Date__c = nextAccount.Anniversary_Date__c,
                                                    Cancellation_Date__c = nextAccount.AccountCancellationDate__c,
                                                    Cancellation_Reason__c = nextAccount.Cancellation_Reason__c,
                                                    Inadequate__c = nextAccount.Inadequate_Available_Features__c,
                                                    Switched_To_Competitor__c = nextAccount.Switched_to_Competitor__c));
            }else{
                System.debug('No Next Level: ' + nextLevel);
                nextLevel = false;
            }
        }
        AccIdToLifeCycleListMap.put(masterId,lcList);
        //System.debug('Records : ' + AccIdToLifeCycleListMap.get(masterId));
    }
    for(Id record : AccIdToLifeCycleListMap.keySet()){
        List<Account_Lifecycle__c> lcList = AccIdToLifeCycleListMap.get(record);
        lifeCyclesToInsert.addAll(lcList);
        if(lcList.size() > 1){
            System.debug('Found Multiple Records: ' + lcList.size() + ' : ' + lcList);
        }
    }

    if(!lifeCyclesToInsert.isEmpty()){
        insert lifeCyclesToInsert;
    }
}
```